# nicescroll bar does not work well when resizing browser

Tags: jquery-plugins, nicescroll

I am using nicescroll  bar and I based most of my work on that now I get a very strange bug:

I have 3 div and nicescroll has been attached to the second div. everything is ok until it comes to responsivnes. for showing content I need to put divs on top of each other. when I resize the browser then the bar for scroll bar goes a way from it's real position(it is supposed to stick to second div); You can see the image as follow:

[image]

Also I tried to create the fiddle link but I could not find the external link of nicescrollbar, by the way my code is as follow:

Css:

```
#boxscroll {
height:220px;
width: 30%;
border: 2px solid #00F;
float:left; 
   }
  .parent{
    width: 100%;
   height: 220px;
   overflow: hidden;
     float:left;
   }
    #test {

     height:220px;
 width: 60%;
 border: 2px solid #00F;
 float:left;
 background-color:blue;

   }
   @media Screen and (max-width:1000px){
     #boxscroll  {
         width:90%;
        float: left;
         height:100px;
          border: 2px solid #00F;
     }
     .parent{
      width: 100%;
      height: 220px;
      overflow: scroll;
       }
     #test
      {
       height:220px;
      width: 95%;
      border: 2px solid #00F;
      float:left;
       background-color:blue;
        }
```

Javascript:

```
   <script
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script src="jquery.nicescroll.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
      $("#boxscroll").height(220);
      $("#boxscroll").niceScroll({
        touchbehavior : false,
        cursorcolor : "#00F",
        cursoropacitymax : 0.7,
        cursorwidth : 6,
        background : "#ccc",
        autohidemode : true
    });

});
```

html:

```
<body>
<div class="parent">
    <div id="test"></div>
    <div id="boxscroll">

        THIS IS A SIMPLE SCROLLABLE DIV
        <h2>Package Description</h2>
        <p>Release Date: August 10, 2010</p>
        <p>
            The <a
                title="http://www.openprinting.org/show_driver.cgi?driver=hpijs"
                rel="nofollow"
                href="http://www.openprinting.org/show_driver.cgi?driver=hpijs">HPIJS</a>
            driver is the free, <a
                title="http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/index.html"
                rel="nofollow"
                href="http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/index.html">open-source
                driver</a> issued by HP for their DeskJet and LaserJet printers. For
            most <a title=""
                href="http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/openprinting/macosx/hpijs#Printers">supported
                printers</a>, this driver produces output quality equivalent to the
            proprietary HP drivers. In photo mode, with photo paper, the output
            quality is very high, especially for the HP DeskJet 990C and later
            models, which auto-detect the paper type in hardware. Photo printing
            is fully supported in the newer 6- and 7-ink models.
        </p>
        <p>A major advantage of using this driver over those supplied by
            HP is the direct interface between HPIJS and the native CUPS
            spooler, which allows printing from any printer over any available
            connection such as USB, AppleTalk, TCP/IP (via LPD and IPP), HP
            JetDirect, and shared windows printers via SAMBA. Additionally, this
            driver utilizes the existing Mac OS X USB &quot;backend&quot; and
            thus does not install any software that might interfere with
            standard USB operation.</p>
        <p>Please note:</p>

        <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
            <p>
                <input type="text" name="a" id="a" /> <input name="" type="button"
                    onclick="this.value+=1" value="1" /> <input name=""
                    type="checkbox" value="1" /> <select name="">
                    <option>- 1 -</option>
                    <option>- 2 -</option>
                    <option>- 3 -</option>
                    <option>- 4 -</option>
                </select>
            </p>
            <textarea name="textarea" id="textarea" cols="45" rows="5"></textarea>
        </form>

        <ul>
            <li>HP does not provide any support for HPLIP or HPIJS on the
                Mac OS X platform.</li>
            <li><a
                href="http://www.linuxfoundation.org/en/OpenPrinting/MacOSX/hpijs-USB">Several
                    HP USB devices</a> may not print successfully over the standard Mac OS
                X USB &quot;backend&quot;. Please <a
                href="http://www.linuxfoundation.org/en/OpenPrinting/MacOSX/hpijs-USB">see
                    this note</a> for more information.</li>
        </ul>
        <h2>Release Notes</h2>
        <ul>
            <li>This release fixes a problem with the PPDs that caused many
                job options such as page orientation, color/grayscale mode, duplex
                printing, etc. to fail.</li>
            <li>HPIJS is HP's universal printer driver for most of their
                non-PostScript printers. It comes as a part of HPLIP, HP Linux
                Imaging and Printing.</li>
            <li>The PPDs for HP printers are now sourced from the HPLIP
                package rather than the OpenPrinting.org database.</li>
            <li>PPDs for printers from other manufacturers are provided by
                OpenPrinting.org.</li>
            <li>Some printers are only partially supported. Printers such
                as<br /> HP LaserJet 1022<br /> HP LaserJet p1505n<br /> HP
                LaserJet p12014<br /> HP LaserJet p2035<br /> require a
                proprietary plug-in for full support. This package does not contain
                or support such plug-ins.
            </li>
        </ul>
        <p>
            <a name="Printer_Set_Up_Instructions"
                id="Printer_Set_Up_Instructions"></a>
        </p>
        <h2>Printer Set Up Instructions</h2>
        <p>To add a printer queue, Leopard (Mac OS X 10.5.x) users should
            use the Print &amp; Fax from System Preferences. Click on the +
            (plus) icon at the lower left. A new window will open. In that
            window, click the Default Browser icon at the top left. Highlight
            your printer in the section below. Use the &quot;Print Using&quot;
            pop-up menu near the bottom of the window to select the correct PPD
            for your printer and click Add.</p>
        <p>Tiger users should open the Printer Setup Utility and click on
            the Add icon at the top of the Printer List window. A new window
            will open. In that window, click the Default Browser icon at the top
            left. Highlight your printer in the section below. Use the
            &quot;Print Using&quot; pop-up menu near the bottom of the window to
            select the correct PPD for your printer and click Add.</p>
        <p>Jaguar (OS X 10.2.x) and Panther (OS X 10.3.x) users should
            open Print Center (Jaguar) or Printer Setup Utility (Panther), hold
            down the Option key, and click the Add Printer button in the Print
            Center toolbar. Within the setup sheet, choose Advanced from the top
            popup menu; then in the &quot;Device:&quot; popup menu select your
            printer by name (it should be the last item in the menu list).
            Finally, select the correct PPD from the model browser and click
            Add.</p>











    </div>
    <div
        style="height: 400px; background-color: black; width: 90%; overflow: hidden; float: left;"></div>
</div>
```

Can anyone help me ?

Comment: Hi Hamed, have you solved the above issue?

Comment: Yes I fixed it with difficulty but I would be happy to hear if you have any idea:)

Comment: I do not have an Idea about it, Could you please share way how to solve this issue?

Comment: could you please help?

Comment: Sure, whenever window size changes kill the nicescroll and create it again:$( window ).resize(function() {$("#tweetWrapper").getNiceScroll().remove();
  myScroll = $("#tweetWrapper").niceScroll({touchbehavior:false,cursorcolor:"#000000",cursoropacitymax:0.7,cursorwidth:6,background:"gray",autohidemode:true});
  $('#tweetWrapper').getNiceScroll().resize();
  tweeterScrollbarEffect(enIDs,tRange,tpIDs,myScroll);